Subscribe to AMM pool creation and generate the pool key structures
I am looking to subscribe to AMM pool creation and generate the pool key structures so that I do not have to load every time the expensive raydium mainnet.json file containing the pool keys.
I have this github as a direction: https://github.com/raydium-io/raydium-sdk-V1-demo/blob/master/src/subNewAmmPool.ts
But still I struggle to achieve it. My idea is being able to update the pool keys in real-time so that swapping even with new token will be possible.

Hello, Stickmen1. Succeeded in find a service to use with subNewAmmPool.ts? Quicknode, Helius, Shyft...?
